# Find the integral of the following function.

Tags: integration, substitution

Question.

[image]

My approach:

[image]

Unfortunately I am stuck right after this step.

I cannot determine what kind of "substitution" would bring the denominator as in the whole function in any solvable form like;

[image]

Not sure if there is any other approach to this sum.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you a facing a very nasty elliptic integral.

Comment: Can you help me solve this..I am finding almost no clue how to tackle this..

Comment: Actually, I am not accustomed with elliptic integrals..

Comment: I suspect that there is a typo. It could be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{b}-\frac{x}{c}}-a}$ which is a totally different story.

Comment: Yes..I can deal with the form you mentioned..But unfortunately I was given this function(mentioned in my question) to integrate..Assuming the question is correct can we actually consider the given function as integrable?

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Comment: Yes..I have been asked this question on quora..https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integral-of-frac-1-sqrt-frac-x-2-b-frac-c-x-a?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__snid3__=3383790840

Comment: Without knowing the relation of the constants there are many different forms the solution can take.

Comment: Once you do know, you can factor the denominator into square roots of constant and/or linear and/or quadratic terms in x and integrate.